# a question about nilpotent p-complements

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm dealing with the following problem, I would appreciate if you could help:

**Problem:** Let $G$ be a finite solvable group whose order is divisible by at least $3$ distinct primes. If $p$-complements of $G$ are nilpotent for any prime $p$ dividing $\vert G \vert$, then $G$ is nilpotent.

**My attempt:** Let's say $\vert G \vert=p_1^{\alpha_1}.p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_n^{\alpha_n},$ where $p_i$'s are distinct primes. We know that in a solvable group Hall - $\pi$ subgroups always exist. If $H_i$ is $p_i$ complement of $G$, then $\vert G:H_i \vert= p_i^{\alpha_i}.$ That is, $H_i$ contains a Sylow-$p_j$ subgroup of $G$ for any $j\neq i.$ Since $H_i$ is nilpotent, these sylow subgroups must be normal in $H_i.$ If I can show that $H_i$'s are  normal in $G$, then the result will follow.

Comment: So if you start with $p_i$, $i\ne j,k$, you have proved that a $p_j$th and a $p_k$th Sylow subgroups centralise each other. Isn't it now easy?